# Multi-select with Select all Option in ANTD React

Tags: reactjs, multi-select, antd

I have a form in which there is a multi select dropdown antd component . 
On change of the select all option , I need to select all the options available with max of 5 tags .

Please find the link of my code in codesandbox here
https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-wind-1swto

Max tag of 5 is sepecified with handleSelectAll function is called on select of options

```
<Form.Item label= 'Column Names'>
                  {getFieldDecorator(`columnNames`, {
                    validateTrigger: ['onChange', 'onBlur'],
                    rules: [
                      {
                        required: true,
                        message: "Please input the Column Names!",
                      },
                    ],
                  })(
                    <Select
                        mode="multiple"
                        placeholder="Please select Columns"
                        maxTagCount={5}
                        onChange={this.handleSelectAll}
                        >
                          <Option key="all" value="all">---SELECT ALL---</Option>
                        {children}
                        </Select>
                  )}
</Form.Item>
```

Expected:

```
On select all is clicked all the options to be selected
On unchecking it all options to be removed
```

Comment: codesandbox link is broken =(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your case, `setFieldsValue` is not working. But you can use `getValueFromEvent`.

```
handleSelectAll = (value) => {
    if (value && value.length && value.includes("all")) {
        if (value.length === all.length + 1) {
            return [];
        }
        return [...all];
    }
    return value;    
}
```

```
<Form.Item label='Column Names'>
    {getFieldDecorator(`columnNames`, {
        validateTrigger: ['onChange', 'onBlur'],
        getValueFromEvent: this.handleSelectAll,
        rules: [
            {
                required: true,
                message: "Please input the Column Names!",
            },
        ],
    })(
        <Select
            mode="multiple"
            placeholder="Please select Columns"
            maxTagCount={5}
            onChange={this.handleSelectAll}
        >
            <Option key="all" value="all">---SELECT ALL---</Option>
            {children}
        </Select>
    )}
</Form.Item>
```

This will work. `handleSelectAll` event returns the value assigned using `getValueFromEvent` and initialized the select component.

Comment: What is `getFieldDecorator ` and how do you use it?

Comment: I mean, as of Antd 4.

Answer (score 0):

On 4.x version.
I think you should set value on form.setFieldsValue({`nameOfFormItem: valueSelected`}}